# Don't mark code comments as incorrect Flyspell

Tags: emacs, comments, flyspell

In emacs flyspell-prog-mode, comments are spell-checked. However, many of my comments are commented blocks of code, and are highlighted as spelling errors. How can I tell Flyspell to ingore all of the symbols used in the program code?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You can't.

Long answer: You have to program it yourself. An entry point is the variable `flyspell-generic-check-word-predicate` where you can supply a function that returns nil if it shouldn't be checked and non-nil if it should, `(point)` is here after the word you want to analyze.

If you have this requirement only for certain modes you can set the `flyspell-mode-predicate` for the mode. E.g. for `python-mode`

```
(put 'python-mode 'flyspell-mode-predicate 'your-python-predicate-function)
```

Comment: And what if I want to generalize this to all prog-modes?

Comment: Right there in the first paragraph: Change `flyspell-generic-check-word-predicate`. But don't use `flyspell-prog-mode` then because it resets it to flyspells own generic one.